# Pinescript. Plotting conditional statement

Tags: if-statement, plot, conditional-statements, pine-script

If the variable `barup` is true, I want it to plot one series; if the variable `bardown` is true, I want it to plot another series value.

My current code yields the error: Cannot use "plot in local scope".

How do I change the following code to make the indicator show the number of days the lows have been above the 30 ema or below the 30 day ema based on the high or low of the current day.

Here is the code I have now:

```
indicator("LandryLight")
bardown = high < ta.ema(close,30)
barup = low > ta.ema(close,30)
if barup
    plot(series=ta.barssince(barup)*-1, title="Consecutive Bars Down", color=color.red, style=plot.style_histogram, linewidth=2)
if bardown
    plot(series=ta.barssince(bardown), title="Consecutive Bars Up", color=color.green, style=plot.style_histogram, linewidth=2)
hline(10,title="Threshold", color=color.white, linestyle=hline.style_dashed, linewidth=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

First Use tag [pine-script]

Try going step by step, and then the plot
I would do it like this:

```
//@version=5
indicator("LandryLight")
bardown = high < ta.ema(close,30)
barup = low > ta.ema(close,30)

barupCont = ta.barssince(barup)*-1
bardownCont = ta.barssince(bardown)
barupOK = barup ? barupCont : na
bardownOK = bardown ? bardownCont : na

plot(series= barupOK, title="Consecutive Bars Down", color=color.red, style=plot.style_histogram, linewidth=2)
plot(series= bardownOK, title="Consecutive Bars Up", color=color.green, style=plot.style_histogram, linewidth=2)
hline(10,title="Threshold", color=color.white, linestyle=hline.style_dashed, linewidth=1)
```